# changing the url in audio() via function url?

Tags: javascript, html

using javascript, i want to play a different sound on the click of an image. i have this code, how to modify to let the onclick attribute set the mp3 file i want to play?

i have this:

```
function play(){
    var audio = new Audio("sounds/apple.mp3");
    audio.play();
}

<img onclick="play()" src="images/apple.png" width="400" height="400" /><br />
```

but lets say i want orange and pear?

i could repeat the play function for each image but that would be to much code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For that I would suggest to use only one function `play` which gonna take an argument `path` is mp3 path:

### JS

```
function play(path){
    var audio = new Audio(path);
    audio.play();
}
```

### HTML

```
<img onclick="play('sounds/apple.mp3')" src="images/apple.png" width="400" height="400" /><br />
<img onclick="play('sounds/orange.mp3')" src="images/orange.png" width="400" height="400" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` should be avoided since generally speaking JS should be in one place only, and that's the respective tag or file. Use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.
You could store your `mp3` filename in a `data-*` attribute:

```js
const play = name => new Audio(`sounds/${name}.mp3`).play();

document.querySelectorAll("[data-audio]").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    play(el.dataset.audio);
  });
});
```

```html
<img data-audio="apple" src="images/apple.png" alt="apple" />
<img data-audio="orange" src="images/orange.png" alt="orange" />
<img data-audio="pear" src="images/pear.png" alt="pear" />
```

Comment: i dont understand your code, i am learning.  I ran the code in my browser and it did not work.  I  worked off your suggestions and came up with this, which also doesnt work. i am beginning to worry this might be an error with my pc setup.

document.getElementById("apple").addEventListener("click",play("sounds/apple.mp3"));

<img id="apple" src="images/apple.png" width="400" height="400" />

Comment: @topdoller your addEventListener function does not look like the one I proposed. Yours calls the play immediately, whilst mine calls it on click. `() => {` makes the difference here.

Comment: Here's a demo that proves the code is working: https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/vL0sykam/1/ @topdoller

Comment: Learn about [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)